# users from trusted domain do not see any search results in SP2010F

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, search-results, trusted-domain

I'm having issues with the SP2010 foundation search. Users coming from another domain (trusts being used) are not able to get search results, however they can traverse the sites. The following KB speaks of a remedy, 
http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/2344518

although only as it seems, applicable **if** having a **enterprise search service application**. MS states that it is also applicable to foundation, but I beg to differ, since there is no such thing as a Enterprise Search Service Appl in the foundation version.

So how do I go about setting my environment up so that users from the trusted domain gets the search results, just as a same domain user does?

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not found another solution than to upgrade to SharePoint 2013 foundation. Since 2013 foundation is running search as a service application it is able to provide the search results. Something that 2010 foundation search never could. It is more or less a comparison of apples and pears.

So my own solution was to run SharePoint 2013 foundation instead.